# Compare groups of items

Tags: user-expectation, interface, e-commerce, comparison

I'm working on a web application allowing users to plan, organize and book an event for a group of people. Users would like to compare and share different options / packages of the event they are organizing. So we are working on a comparison tool, similar to what you can find in many e-commerce website. But compared to the majority of these comparison tools, users can compare packages of items in our case, which makes ergonomics and understanding much more complicated.

The comparison view isn't the most complicated to design. The most complicated thing is to give the possibility to the user to create a comparison, then to create different packages in this comparison and finally to add items in these different packages.

Do you have any tips, food for thought or know similar products I can benchmark ?

[image: Classic comparison tool]

[image: Our comparison tool]

Comment: Your visuals are appreciated, but they're a little abstract. Would you be able to give us a glimpse of what your comparison tool will look like with screenshots, and where you think there might be a UX problem?

Comment: Hi Damien, the question is not clear. As you said, this looks like a typical pattern used for comparing eCommerce sites. So, it's unclear what's the difference from your or what specific problem you're referring to. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Yes visual are abstract because we are still in research and do not have any more advanced user interface screenshots.

In typical comparing tools you will compare several similar items, for example 3 TVs. In our case you will compare several options of events, but an option is made of several items. For example one option can be a karting activity with a diner in a restaurant, a second option can be a laser tag activity with a drink in a bar, ect ...

Answer (score 1):

So for one, some research needs to be done in order to know what users are usually trying to find out about an event. e.g. are they wondering about the venue/location, size maybe, duration, maybe one of the options is a concert, someone suggested that you watch the Titanic for the 70th time etc. And then you group those. So, location, size, duration, entertainment, dress code, etc.

This then can be placed on a comparison chart, maybe like so:

[image: TABLE]

Of course it should look better than this. Anywho, if you can switch the values into checkmarks somehow, (e.g. by asking "near city centre" instead of "location") it can help make the comparison chart a bit less cluttered.